# What's another way to say that a person is not without means or is not destitute?

Tags: word-request

I need a word that means a person is financially stable and isn't poor I.E.  ( I see you are not destitute, or without means..  ) how could I word this or what is a more sophisticated way to say this?

Answer (score 1):

**Financially secure** might be a good fit depending on the context. Here's the [link](https://www.quicken.com/what-financial-security) to the website I found that talks about the concept of financial security and what it means:

> **Financial security** refers to the peace of mind you feel when you aren't worried about your income being enough to cover your expenses. It also means that you have enough money saved to cover emergencies and your future financial goals. When you are financially secure, your stress levels goes down, leaving you free to focus on other issues.

I think they're doing a pretty good job explaining what it is. It's a rather basic concept.

Answer (score 0):

"Not a charity case". This might work very well.

Comment: This answer would be improved with references to the phrase's meaning.